# Docker build error with Maven when trying to mvn package

Tags: maven, docker

I am trying to run a Maven Project with Docker and when I try to build it I get
`Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.maven.boot.plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar`
as an error when the building process is at mvn package. Im new to working with Maven and Docker.

I tried with including different Maven and Java Versions but that just put some errors away.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt-get install -y maven
COPY pom.xml /usr/local/service/pom.xml
COPY src /usr/local/service/src
WORKDIR /usr/local/service
RUN mvn package
CMD ["java", "-cp", "target/sensor-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "sensor/SensorControl"]
```

Do you guys know where the problem could be?

Comment: Why do you rung `apt-get install -y maven` cause you already inherit from a base image `maven:3.5-jdk-8`?  How do you run that build and the container...? Furthermore what is the reason to built inside a Docker container?

Comment: @khmarbaise Removing that line actually solved my problem. Thanks for pointing that mistake out.